# File/Save for a VSIX custom file editor that hosts a WPF Control

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, vsix

I have been developing a Visual Studio extension to host custom diagrams within projects. The diagrams are developed using WPF user controls and I am now working on implementing the custom editor to host the diagrams. I followed the VSSDK example to implement a designer over an XML file (https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/WPFDesigner_XML) and this all works to load the XML into the diagram and properly display the visuals. However, I also need to implement a custom save process with a custom file extension using File/Save and File/Save As. The WPF example has implemented saving the file in the background when idle. When I do a File/Save, the data is not properly saved to XML file through the custom save method and when I do a File/Save As, I am not seeing the custom file extensions.

I also reviewed the VSSDK example to implement a WinForms editor with a toolbox (https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/Editor_With_Toolbox) which does demonstrate using File/Save, File/Save As and custom file extensions. It appears that the key to File/Save functionality is in implementing `IPersistFileFormat` and `IVsPersistDocData`. The methods for these interfaces also seem to require the Override implementation of WindowPane.Window.
The WinForm example for the Window Override simply returns the RichTextBox control as shown below:

```
public override IWin32Window Window
{
    get
    {
        return editorControl;
    }
}
```

However in using WPF, doing the same with the WPF user control does not work. I am looking for the bridge between these two examples to utilize `IPersistFileFormat` and `IVsPersistDocData` when hosting a WPF user control.

I did try to provide a window wrapper class that would utilize a Diagnostics Process window handle as discussed in this article: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/20347/how-to-get-iwin32window-handle-used-in-windows-for. But this returned a Default value and failed to work.

To summarize, how can I have the functionality of File/Save for a custom file editor that hosts a WPF control?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would help. I have a custom editor for FastReport Files (.frx) and show this in a WPF UserControl. In the CreateEditorInstance, I create a textbuffer and map the IPersistDocData interface

```
try
   {
     var localRegistry = ILocalRegistry)GetService(typeof(SLocalRegistry));
     if (localRegistry != null)
         {
           IntPtr ptr;
           var iid = typeof(IVsTextLines).GUID;
           var CLSID_VsTextBuffer = typeof(VsTextBufferClass).GUID;
           localRegistry.CreateInstance(CLSID_VsTextBuffer, null, ref iid, 1 /*CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER*/, out ptr);
            try
               {
                 textBuffer = Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(ptr) as IVsTextLines;
               }
             finally
               {
                 Marshal.Release(ptr); 
                }

                // It is important to site the TextBuffer object
                var objWSite = (IObjectWithSite)textBuffer;
                if (objWSite != null)
                   {
                     var oleServiceProvider = (IOleServiceProvider)GetService(typeof(IOleServiceProvider));
                     objWSite.SetSite(oleServiceProvider);
                   }

                    persistDoc = textBuffer as IVsPersistDocData2;
                }
```

Then, I use a ViewModel that implements IVsRunningDocTableEvents3 to catch the OnBeforeSave event in the RunningDocTable. When this fires, I write the contents of the editor to the textbuffer. Save and Save As can now do their thing with the correct file contents.

BTW: My main use for the IVsPersistDocData2 stuff is to manage the DocumentDirty flag when the custom editor changes (I don't save the contents of the editor to the underlying file until the OnBeforeSave event).